# Нужно ли обособлять слово соответственно?

Tags: запятая

Добрый день! Нужна ли запятая в следующем тексте: "Повышение налоговой ставки произошло в ноябре на 13 процентов и 15 % в декабре (?) соответственно.

Comment: @гулайым, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

При таком порядке слов (проценты привязаны к своим датам) не нужно слово "соответственно".
Возможен вариант:

"Повышение налоговой ставки происходило в ноябре и декабре, на 13 и 15 процентов соответственно".

Слово "соответственно" здесь указывает на то, что проценты соответствуют месяцам - в порядке упоминания того и другого в тексте. Запятая не нужна.