# Соответственно избили?

Tags: семантика

*Футболисты сборной России К. и М. задержаны полицией за драки в Москве, сообщает телеканал "Сплетни ТВ".
По информации медиа, нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара **соответственно** избили в московском кафе чиновника П. и генерального директора Г.*

Зачем тут слово "соответственно"?!

Answer (score 2):

Телеканал "Сплетни ТВ" излагает свои сплетни канцелярским языком, да еще и с ошибками. Думаю. нападающий К. избил чиновника П, а полузащитник М. избил генерального директора Г.
Вопрос, как исправить то, что написано. Как варинат:

**Нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара избили в московском кафе чиновника П. и генерального директора Г. соответственно.**

Дополнение.
Драки (мн. ч.) в Москве, но избили в московском кафе (ед. ч.). То есть две драки, но обе в одном кафе?

Новая версия.
Другое издание пишет:

> Футболисты сборной России А. К. и П. М. избили чиновника министерства промышленности и торговли РФ Д. П., сообщает телеграм-канал Mash.
>   По информации аккаунта, инцидент случился в кофейне на северо-западе Москвы, куда нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара соответственно пришли позавтракать.

Выходит, все-таки прав grizzly:  А. К. и П. М. — это нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара **соответственно**. Хотя текст сообщения и варьируется от сайта к сайту, безграмотное употребление слова *соответственно* удивительным образом сохранено везде.

Comment: Разве запятая в последнем предложении нужна?

Comment: @grizzly Не уверен. Пишут и так, и эдак. А как правильно?

Comment: Alex_ander Считает, что запятая не нужна: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47668/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: Так что я, пожалуй, уберу ее.

Comment: Тоже думаю, что не нужна. Хотя я не смог найти подтверждения. Может, это тот случай, когда просто нет никаких оснований для запятой?

Comment: Драка о которой идет речь - одна. Кто кого бил, пока точно не установлено. Да, были еще две драки - но это до описываемых событий. Ребята вообще крепко погуляли в ту ночь.

Comment: По сути. *Нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара избили в московском кафе чиновника П. и генерального директора Г. соответственно.* - это вариант. Мне в голову не пришло, что тут можно так понять, что К. и М. избили П. и Г. - каждый своего потерпевшего. Спасибо. *"Сплетни ТВ"* - это моё творчество, экземплификант. На самом деле там реальный и известный канал стоял.

Comment: А разве на самом деле каждый "своего" обидел? В одной из ранних версий я читал только про никак не названного "чиновника" - второго пострадавшего позже "учли".

Comment: @Alex_ander, я добавил новую версию к ответу.

Answer (score 2):

"Соответствие" не должно выходить за рамки одного предложения и не должно цепляться за слова, к которым оно не относится. Оно было бы полезно в случае, если бы в одном и том же предложении сначала перечислили имена людей, а затем (вдогонку) их должности. Тогда такое уточнение было бы однозначным:

> Футболисты сборной России **К. и М.** ,  **нападающий Зенита и полузащитник
>   Краснодара соответственно**, сделали то-то.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, имелось в виду, что К. и М. играют в Зените и Краснодаре соответственно. Да, такое употребление в другом абзаце сбивает с толку. Но если бы даже они били порознь, каждый своего, тогда "соответственно" стояло бы в конце предложения.

Ошибка могла возникнуть в результате неаккуратной правки такого, например, предложения: "футболисты К. и М., нападающий Зенита и полузащитник Краснодара соответственно, избили в московском кафе...".

Comment: Я бы согласился, но М_Г более остроумную версию дал. У каждого была свой потерпевший, К. и М. били П. и Г. соответственно. Это куда более похоже на правду. Как все было - скоро узнаем, дело нашумевшее.

Answer (score 0):

Да, "соответственно" здесь не нужно. Спасибо вам, что зорко следите и оперативно исправляете ошибки телеканала "Сплетни ТВ". Вы помогаете нам стать лучше!

Comment: Нападающий избил П., а полузащитник — Г. Отсюда и «соответственно». Лишь порядок слов хромает.

Comment: Дело не в этом. Здесь явная стилистическая погрешность. Речь о вопиющем хулиганстве, короткая заметка - и вдруг такие дотошные подробности, кто кого соответственно бил. "Соответственно избили" (пусть даже эти слова стоят не рядом, а через одно-два) - глаза не режет?

Comment: Хотел вписаться в шутейный тон Вашего ответа.